# Server 2012 MS Update Causes Boot Loop - How to Stop or Diagnose?

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012, windows-server

Running an EC2 instance with Server 2012. Windows is set to Automatically Install Updates. I am not sure what update is causing it, but it was installed after December 1. When this update reboots the server, the server goes into a boot loop where it comes back up for 20 seconds, then goes back down again. I can't RDP to it given the short window. Restoring the root drive back to the December 1 version works, but with auto-updates installed, I am afraid it will go down again. I am disabling auto updates for now.

Here is a screen shot of the 12/1 drive version and "Check for Updates" ran. There are 2 "important" which I assume are the only ones that are auto-installed, and 3 option.

Important: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqrvx.jpg

Optional: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9ArF.jpg

Comment: If `reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl" -v AutoReboot` shows 1 then reset it to `0`. See whether  [this article](https://www.tecknowledgebase.com/6367/how-to-disable-the-automatic-restart-on-system-failure-in-windows-7/) is applicable to Windows Server…

Comment: This is off-topc here... You should move this over to [sf] as this place is for programming related questions...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any of these have a known issue of causing the server to be stuck in a boot loop. If you know which updates were installed at that date, then why not remove those updates and see if it corrects your issue?

What events are triggering in the event viewer when the machine goes down?

Comment: I have hidden the updates that caused the issue. I am worried about subsequent updates. I can't get into the box to see the Event Viewer.

Comment: Is this a virtual or physical machine? Can you boot the machine into safe mode?

Comment: It is a virtual machine on Ec2.